# Need to count incidents found multiple times within a text file

Tags: c#, regex, loops, while-loop

I'm really trying to count the number of times a regex is found within a text but there are many regex to be found within a text file. 
the problem is that my code only counts the first time, the subsequent IF that contains the other regexes will not count, Everything works but the counting of on each line that error occurred :(

could  you please shed some light?

```
int counter = 1;
string liner;
string pattern = @"access-group\s+\w+\s+out\s+interface\s+\w+";
Boolean foundMatch;

int totalOUTgroups = Lines(ofd.FileName)
.Select(line => Regex.Matches(line, pattern).Count)
.Sum();


if (totalOUTgroups > 0)
{
    richTextBox2.SelectionFont = new Font("Courier New", 8);
    richTextBox2.AppendText(">>> ACls installed by using access-group using the keyword OUT are NOT supported: " + "\u2028");
    richTextBox2.AppendText(">>> Total of incidences found: " + totalOUTgroups.ToString() + "\u2028");

    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
    while ((liner = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        foundMatch = performMatch(pattern, liner);

        if (foundMatch)
        {
            richTextBox2.AppendText("Line: " + counter + " " + liner + "\r\n");
        }
        counter++;

    }

}
//Will end 1
// 2 Mark echo-reply ICMP

int counter2 = 1;
string liner2;
string pattern2 = @"/^(?=.*\baccess-list\b)(?=.*\beq echo-reply\b).*$/gm";
Boolean foundMatch2;

int totalIntACLInt = Lines(ofd.FileName)
       .Select(line => Regex.Matches(line, pattern2).Count)
       .Sum();

if (totalIntACLInt > 0)
{
    richTextBox2.SelectionFont = new Font("Courier New", 8);
    richTextBox2.AppendText(" " + "\u2028");
    richTextBox2.AppendText(">>> Echo-reply is not necessary: " + "\u2028");
    richTextBox2.AppendText(">>> Total of incidences found: " + totalIntACLInt.ToString() + "\u2028");

    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(ofd.FileName);
    while ((liner2 = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        foundMatch2 = performMatch(pattern2, liner2);

        if (foundMatch2)
        {
            richTextBox2.AppendText("Line:" + counter2 + " " + liner2 + "\r\n");

        }
        counter2++;


    }
}
```

Comment: What i don't understand is why you read (LINQ + IF statement) the same file twice while you could do it in one time ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, then the problem you're having is most likely tied to your implementation of `performMatch()`.  Post the code for `performMatch()` if you want help debugging that.

As @Justin lurman pointed out, try printing out each line and line number while only iterating through the file once. If `Regex.Matches(line, pattern)` is already working for you, then just make use of that.

For example:

```
int counter = 1;
string pattern = @"access-group\s+\w+\s+out\s+interface\s+\w+";    
var totalMatches = 0;
var output = new StringBuilder();

foreach(var line in Lines(ofd.FileName))
{
     var matches = Regex.Matches(line, pattern).Count;
     if (matches > 0)
     {
        totalMatches += matches;
        output.AppendLine(string.Format("Line: {0} {1}", counter, line));
     }
     counter++;
}

if(toatlMatches > 0)
{
   richTextBox2.SelectionFont = new Font("Courier New", 8);
   richTextBox2.AppendText(">>> ACls installed by using access-group using the keyword OUT are NOT supported: " + "\u2028");
   richTextBox2.AppendText(">>> Total of incidences found: " + totalMatches.ToString() + "\u2028");
   richTextBox2.AppendText(output.ToString());
}
```

As a warning **I haven't compiled or tested the code** above, so use it as a guideline.  You can certainly improve upon the code further.  To start you could refactor your repeated code into methods.

## Update

OK, I still don't know that I'm clear on what exactly your problem is, but I wrote out some code that should achieve what it is that I think you're trying to accomplish.  While writing my code I noticed some things about the code you posted that may be causing issues for you.

- Your second regex `/^(?=.*\baccess-list\b)(?=.*\beq echo-reply\b).*$/gm` doesn't look like a valid .NET regex, it looks like a [JavaScript regex literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)
- You're appending text to a RichTextBox control, which has a max length property you may be exceeding. I doubt you're writing out that much text, but it's possible.

> When this property is set to 0, the maximum length of the text that can be entered in the control is 64 KB of characters
>   - [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.maxlength%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here is the relevant snippet from the console app I wrote that reads a text file, line by line, and applies a collection of regexes to each line.  If a match is found it stores the pertinent information about each match and then prints out its finding once all lines have been examined.

```
class CommonError
{
    public Regex Pattern { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public List<KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<string>>> Details { get; private set; }

    public CommonError(Regex pattern, string message)
    {
        Pattern = pattern;
        Message = message;
        Details = new List<KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<string>>>();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //take a file read it once and while reading each line check if that line matches any of a slew of regexes.
        //if it does match a regex then add the line number and the matching text into a collection of matches for that regex.
        //at the end output all the matches by regex and the totals for each pattern. Along with printing each match also print the line it was found on. 

        var errorsToFind = new List<CommonError>()
        { 
           new CommonError(new Regex(@"access-group\s+\w+\s+out\s+interface\s+\w+"), "ACls installed by using access-group using the keyword OUT are NOT supported"),
           new CommonError(new Regex(@"^(?=.*\baccess-list\b)(?=.*\beq echo-reply\b).*$"), "Echo-reply is not necessary")
        };

        var errorsFound = FindCommonErrorsInFile(".\\test-file.txt", errorsToFind);

        foreach (var error in errorsFound)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("total incidences found: " + error.Details.Count);
            error.Details.ForEach(d => Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Line {0} {1}", d.Key, string.Join(",", d.Value))));
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<CommonError> FindCommonErrorsInFile(string pathToFile, IEnumerable<CommonError> errorsToFind)
    {
        var lineNumber = 1;
        foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(pathToFile))
        {
            foreach (var error in errorsToFind)
            {
                var matches = error.Pattern.Matches(line);
                if(matches.Count == 0) continue;

                var rawMatches = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value);
                error.Details.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, IEnumerable<string>>(lineNumber, rawMatches));
            }
            lineNumber++;
        }
        return errorsToFind.Where(e => e.Details.Count > 0);
    }
}
```

If you're still having issues give this code a try--this time **I actually compiled it and tested it.**  Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Gowansg
I did what you said, and again, works great for the first check,
there are many of them, that will check through the text for different exceptions, count them and print them with their line numbers. 
the problem is that only the first ones are printed the subsequent ones are not:

Comment: >>> ACls installed by using access-group using the keyword OUT are NOT supported: 
>>> Total of incidences found: 4
Line: 164 access-group acl_outside out interface outside
Line: 165 access-group acl_mama out interface outside
Line: 166 access-group acl_chica out interface outside
Line: 167 access-group acl_papa out interface outside
 
>>> ACS with interface defined is not accepted: 
>>> Total of incidences found: 2
Line:  access-list outside_access_in permit tcp any interface inside eq ssh
Line:  access-list outside_access_in permit tcp any interface dmz

Comment: All I need is to continue to count the lines for the next REGEX on the text, this code only checks for the FIRST loop

Comment: @The_Kerb So you only see line numbers in your output for matches found with your first regex?  You still see all the other information--total incidences found, the text from each matching line--for subsequent matches? The only piece of information missing from those subsequent matches is the line number? Is that correct?

Comment: I tried your logic and it worked, what I'm having problems now is to pass it into my richtextbox response but that should be minor. Thank you very much.